# Subgroups of a group disjoint from a given subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with $M$ a specified subgroup. One way of constructing representations of $G$ from $M$ is by induction, however if the index of $M$ in $G$ is large, then the composition series of induced representations can be tricky to determine.

If one could instead find an intermediary subgroup $M \leq P \leq G$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $P$ then we could lift our representation from $M$ to $P$, before inducing from $P$ to $G$, thus reducing the index by a factor of $\left| P : M \right|$.

In such a case, $P$ is a split extension of $M$ in $G$, and so if $M \cong P/U$ for some normal subgroup $U \leq P$, then $P$ is the internal semi-direct product of $U$ and $M$ in $G$. Thus determining such a $P$ is equivalent to choosing a subgroup $U$ of $G$ with $U \cap M = \left\{ e \right\}$.

Then since $P = MU$, the factor by which we reduce is $\left| MU :U \right| = \left| U \right|$, and so we are left with the problem of determining a subgroup $U$ of $G$ such that $U \cap M = \left\{e\right\}$ and that maximises $\left| U \right|$.

Is there any systematic way of determining such a $U$?

---

Edit: I think we also have to add the restrictions that $MU$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that $U$ is normal in $MU$.

Comment: Are you saying that any subgroup $U$ that has trivial intersection with $M$ works?

Comment: I think there's an issue about $U$ being normal in $MU$, but I'm unsure about this too.

Comment: $MU$ is not guaranteed to be a subgroup of $G$ (however, $U$ normal in $G$ or in $P$ is enough to say it is)

Comment: I can see that $U$ being normal in $G$ guarantees that $MU$ is a subgroup of $G$. We also need that $U$ is normal in $MU$, which is guaranteed by $U$ being normal in $G$. But do we denote necessarily have the converse? That is, could we have that $MU$ is a subgroup of $G$, with $U$ normal in $MU$, and with $U$ not normal in $G$? The reason I ask is because I am looking to maximise $\left| U \right|$ with $U$ disjoint from $M$, and with $MU$ a subgroup such that $U$ is normal in $MU$.

Comment: What I am saying is that "$U$ is normal in $MU$" is hard to check... maybe you could start with the weaker $U \leq G$, $U \cap M = 1$ and $MU=UM$? This guarantees that $P=MU$ is a subgroup, and then you could consider all normal subgroups of $P$ that do not contain $M$.

Comment: Okay sure! I see what you're saying, thanks!

Comment: Actually a stronger condition, but probably much easier to check, would be looking for $U \leq G$ with $M \cap U = 1$ but $M \leq N_G(U)$ (which guarantees $MU=UM$).

Comment: Maybe not of any help, but your idea works in case $M$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, and $P$ is its normalizer $N_G(M)$: $M$ is normal in $N_G(M)$ and by Schur-Zassenhaus, you can find a complement $U \leq N_G(M)$ with $N_G(M)=MU, M \cap U=1$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks for your comment, but I need that $U$ is normal in $MU$ rather than $M$ normal. $M$ is the subgroup I start with, and $U$ is the complement I’m trying to find.

Comment: @AdamHiggins OK I see it now. Never mind, was just thinking along your interesting question and the subsequent remarks made by the others. I gave you a +1 for the post by the way!

Comment: @NickyHekster thanks! Interesting to hear your thoughts anyway :)